# Is it possible to retrieve the name of a file from redirection?

Tags: c, file, stdin

I am doing some basic file manipulations, and would like to store the name the file passed to an executable C program and create a new file that has an extension tacked on the original filename. For example, if this were what I typed on the command line:

```
a.out < some_file.txt
```

Where `a.out` is an executable, is there a way to get the string `some_file.txt`, so I could open up a new file and call it `some_file.text.mod` or something else?

`argv[0]` gets you `a.out`, and  in scripting you could use `$1` to access arguments (but not the filenames used in redirection), but neither of those is much use here.

Any ideas?

Comment: A shell script called with input redirected to a file and no other parameter will give you nothing in `$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime (and almost always in practice) `/proc/self/fd/0` could be a symbolic link to the file. (But the symlink could be crappy, e.g. for a pipe, and this is Linux specific).

So from inside your `a.out` you could call the `readlink(2)` system call on `/proc/self/fd/0`

But doing that is a bit *disgusting*. However it works:

```
% ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 < ~/.zshrc
lr-x------ 1 basile basile 64 Nov  6 19:22 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /home/basile/.zshrc

% date | ls -l /proc/self/fd/0
lr-x------ 1 basile basile 64 Nov  6 19:23 /proc/self/fd/0 -> pipe:[599869]
```

Again, it is **highly Linux specific** and not portable to other Posix systems.

Comment: Oj! That is messy, I think I shall figure out another way to name this file. Thanks for such a detailed response!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible on some platforms, using platform specific constructs.

e.g. on linux you can call readlink() on /proc/self/fd/0

Other forms of redirection will not provide access to the file name, there might not be a file - the data might be supplied through a pipe.

For your case, you're likely better off letting the user decide the output filename in the cases the input is redirected through stdin

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I hadn't thought about other situations where it might not be a file, that makes sense though now that it wouldn't be easily possible.